# How to Map Data Types to Custom Types?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, user-interface, proxy

Consider the following function:

```
public function foo(bar1:int, bar2:uint, bar3:String, bar4:Boolean):void{}
```

What I want is to have the different types of data represented by custom named types which are essentially representing the original data types. In other words, I would like to proxy the data types and have a valid function as following:

```
public function foo(bar1:PAR_Bar1, bar2:PAR_Bar2, bar3:PAR_Bar3, bar4:PAR_Bar4):void{}
```

so PAR_Bar1 would proxy the `int` data type, PAR_Bar2 would proxy the `uint` data type, so on and so forth.

The reason I need this is because I'm using a debugger with a GUI that can run methods and allows changing function parameter values in real-time, the issue is that the debugger can't tell me what parameter I'm changing, it only displays the data type of a parameter. So if I need to change 10 different parameters all of type int, the debuggers display all of them as int and not by their names.

I think that if I use proxy types I can easily differentiate between parameters.

So, my question: **Is it possible to proxy data types? I mean map specific data types to custom data types that would represent the base data types?**

EDIT: I'm using the [Monster Debugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) and this is the window of a method called in real-time:
[image]

As you can see, I don't get the parameters' names but their type (int).

Comment: That sounds like a pretty terrible debugger, what are you using?

Comment: I have updated the post for more details about the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are no ways of aliasing types.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you changed your debugger but since this is a proper question...
You can create a class just like any constant:

```
const PAR_Bar1:Class = uint;
```

Let's hope your debugger will identify this class and not its mother.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried what you told me, and if I create the constant outside the main class I get this error: "5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition" and if I declare it inside the main class, I get this error: "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: PAR_Bar1."

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are going to use this for but have you considered using an untyped variable definition?

```
public function foo(bar1:*, bar2:*, bar3:*, bar4:*):void{}
```

Then using this to get the class of the variables?

```
var PAR_Bar1:Class = Object(bar1).constructor;
```

EDIT: Ah ignore this one, re-read your question and realised this won't help you.

Comment: Yes, I think that what I want (aliasing types) isn't even possible.